# Search a string in a line in a text file and copy it to another text file or a new variable

Tags: batch-file, search, text-files

I have a problem with batch and I can't get behind it. I searched Google and Stack Overflow for hours, and now I'm asking the question myself because nobody seemed to have this exact problem yet or I simply can't find it. I have even searched last results page on Google (!).

So I have coded a batch file that automatically pulls file names from a server and puts them into a text file along with the files path. Now I have a file that looks roughly like this:

```
q:\0003730310008520150610120508\1_PY98200_00084_00085_09_20150610_140447.antfzg
q:\000649A7B0008520150630085701\1_KP40610_00084_00085_09_20150630_105647.antfzg
q:\000649A7B0008520150630085701\1_KP40610_00084_00085_09_20150630_110508.antfzg
q:\00161083B0008520150429065335\1_J281516_00084_00085_09_20150429_085326.antfzg
q:\00161083B0008520150429122000\1_PV92717_00084_00085_09_20150429_141952.antfzg
q:\00161083B0008520150515065834\1_VY65621_00084_00085_09_20150515_085802.antfzg
q:\00161083B0008520150527075722\1_D894693_00084_00085_09_20150527_095704.antfzg
q:\00161083B0008520150602075809\1_L893216_00084_00085_09_20150602_095757.antfzg
q:\00161083B0008520150608082553\1_VT04798_00084_00085_09_20150608_102033.antfzg
q:\00161083B0008520150610080050\1_LF22563_00084_00085_09_20150610_100016.antfzg
q:\00161083B0008520150623132003\1_VN57593_00084_00085_09_20150623_151927.antfzg
```

Now I want to search for a specific article number that looks like this for the first example: `PY98200` (the part directly behind `1_`). If that is found in the file, copy the entire line containing the string into either a new variable or a new text file. If the number exists multiple times, then all lines should be copied, too.

I tried different **for** loops, but I failed because I am not that experienced with batch coding.

Comment: `type "original_text_file.txt"|find "PY98200" > new_text_file.txt` ?

Comment: should I write a loop for this or does it work by itself?

Comment: you don't need a loop.Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

The command line for this task as posted by [npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka) is:

```
type "original_text_file.txt" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "PY98200" > "new_text_file.txt"
```

How it works?

[type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491026.aspx) is an internal command of command processor `cmd.exe` which outputs the contents of a text file to **stdout** (standard output) which is displayed usually in console window.

The output of **type** is [piped](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) with `|` from **stdout**  of **type** to **stdin** (standard input) of standard Windows console application **find**.

[find](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490906.aspx) is a very small console application to find a simple, non regular expression string in lines of a text file and which by default outputs to **stdout** all lines containing the searched string. A more powerful console application to find strings in files is [findstr](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx). But **find** has the feature needed for this task, too.

The output of **find** is redirected with `>` to file `new_text_file.txt` in current directory.

Why not calling **find** directly with the name of the text file?

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "PY98200" "original_text_file.txt" > "new_text_file.txt"
```

With the command line above **find** outputs also an empty line and one more line containing the name of the file before the lines containing the searched string. This is useful if multiple files are searched for lines containing a string and in output it is important to know which lines are from which file.

But `new_text_file.txt` should contain only the lines containing `PY98200` without any additional information about source. Therefore the command **type** is used to let **find** read contents of `original_text_file.txt` via **stdin** which avoids printing the two header lines **find** outputs for each file to file `new_text_file.txt`.

An alternate command line for this task would be:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:PY98200 "original_text_file.txt" > "new_text_file.txt"
```

For more details about the used commands respectively console applications, open a command prompt window, execute the following commands and read all help pages output by each command into the console window.

- `type /?`
- `find /?`
- `findstr /?`

All standard commands / console applications of Windows output help on running them with parameter `/?` which for some commands is more accurate then online documentation.